# Do people who voted to close get an email when a comment is left on an on-hold question?

Tags: support

When a question is put on hold, there's a note that mentions to either edit the question or leave a comment to remove the hold.

Do the users or moderator(s) who put the question on hold receive a notification when either action is done?

Comment: Afaik they (diamond mods) don't. If you get no response and it isn't reopened after some time, you could flag for moderator attention and have them look at it. But give it some time before you do, and really address all the issues.

Comment: One can also use `@` to send direct notification to those who closed. Usually the first to close will leave auto-generated comment so best approach him first.

Answer (score 3):

No, users who put a question on hold do not get notifications for edits or changes.

However, when you edit a closed question, it is placed in the reopen queue, where it will be reviewed by different users who may reopen it if has addressed the specified issues. If you are *absolutely sure* a question should be open and it isn't, feel free to flag a mod. Use the "other" reason, and explain exactly why the question should be reopened.